# Vectorizing a Numpy operation on differently shaped matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I just cannot find a solution to the following problem:

Consider two NumPy.arrays, one of shape (10,64,10) and one of (x, 64).

Array A (10,64,10) represents 10 classes with 64 features and over each of these features I got a PDF split in 10 bins --> (Classes, Features, Bins). Each value in that innermost array represents a probability.

```
[[[0.62, 0.,   0.  ],
  [0.12, 0.09, 0.01],
  [0.59, 0.01, 0.  ],
  [0.62, 0.,   0.  ]],
 [[0.62, 0.,   0.  ],
  [0.59, 0.01, 0.  ],
  [0.62, 0.,   0.  ],
  [0.62, 0.,   0.  ]]]
```

(simplified to (2,4,3) so you can test it by copying it directly. The representating classes are "0" and "1")

Array B (X, 64) are the instance of a dataset X and the bin-index the i`th feature belongs to\

```
[[0, 0, 2, 1]
 [0, 0, 1, 0]
 [0, 2, 1, 0]]
```

(simplified to (X=3, 4))

What I want to do is for each row in Array B, e.g. [0, 0, 2, 1] I want to get the probability that when the bin for the first feature is 0 the class is "1" and that the class is "0".

The expected output for the first instance here would be:
"0" = `[0.62, 0.12, 0.00, 0.00]`
"1" = `[0.62, 0.59, 0.00, 0.00]`
and if possible then for all X instances.
I do not expect any kind of Dictionary or anything alike but just some array that contains the values in a somewhat sorted manner (can also be another sort than shown in the example)

Of course, I could do all this in giant nested for-loops, but I want at least some vectorization. As anybody any good suggestions, our answer does not have to be a full-fledged solution.

**EDIT**:
The best nested loop I came up with was

```
prediction = np.empty((bins.shape[0], histograms.shape[1], histograms.shape[0]))
for n, instance in enumerate(bins):

    for i, instance_bin in enumerate(instance):
        prediction[n,i] = histograms[:,i, instance_bin] # Prob for every class x that the bin given in "instance_bin" of feature "i" corresponds to a possible instance of that class
```

histograms = Array A;
bins = Array B

Please also tell me of every other bad-practise if you find any in my way of working with numpy or anything else in this snipped.

Comment: Often the nested loops is a good way to start - it gives us something clear to aim for.  Word descriptions can be ambiguous.  Otherwise we are stuck with suggesting a combination of actions that makes most sense, given the dimensions.

Comment: That's why I'm not sure if my solution is right

Comment: Expaned my question, with a working nested loop